# How to loop through every square in a rectangle?

Tags: c#, loops, for-loop

In c#, I want to loop through every square possible in a rectangle. The square size is much smaller than the rectangle dimensions. But note that I don't mean loop through every square in a grid pattern, I mean every square at any type of location (not limited to a grid). Its like randomly picking a square at a random location, but it needs to go through all possible locations and only get each one once (no duplicates).

Does anyone know of an algorithm for this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean, not limited to a grid? Any rectangle contains an infinite amount of smaller rectangles.

Comment: Yes, so a way to loop through all the possible smaller squares that is contained in the rectangle. Note that this is on an image with pixels, so I dont think there is infinite amount, since coordinates are integers.

Comment: That wasn't a yes/no question. Can you elaborate on how your rectangle is stored/marked/etc?

Comment: The rectangle is just a set of 4 (x,y) coordinates, and the smaller square is just an int representing the length of it's side.

Comment: There is a grid that is to be respected if your units are integer pixels, then.

Comment: Yes, but I mean like, a possible square can be in the top left most of the rectangle (0,0), and then it can also be so that the top left pixel of the square is at location (1,0). So this is not restricting to a grid, where if it was, then the square could not be at (1,1), it would have to be at (q,0) or (0,q) or (q,q) assuming q is the length of the square side. This is what I mean by grid.

Comment: Is the square a constant size for this, or do u mean any size square?

Comment: Well really the function should take the coordinates of the rectangle and then the length of the square as inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al you need to do is set an origin (say, left-top), find out the maximum side length from that location, and iterate from 1 to that value for every pixel in your image.

Class names are fictional, adapt to your own needs.

```
IEnumerable<Rectangle> AllSquaresIn(Rectangle rect)
{
    for (int x = 0; i x < rect.Width; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rect.Height; y++)
        {
            int maxLength = Math.Min(rect.Width - x, rect.Height - y);
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++)
            {
                yield return new Rectangle(x, y, x + i, y + i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since `i` is always positive, it will be impossible to have duplicate rectangles.

---

Since it appears from the comments that you only want the rectangles of a given size:

```
IEnumerable<Rectangle> AllSquaresIn(Rectangle rect, int length)
{
    for (int x = 0; i x < rect.Width - length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < rect.Height - length; y++)
        {
            yield return new Rectangle(x, y, x + length, y + length);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the new rectangle a square? I'm trying to loop through (and return) only squares contained in the rectangle.

Comment: Assuming a `Rectangle` constructor `(x1, y1, x2, y2)`, `x2-x1==y2-y1` in all cases, so yes. Call it `Square` and give it different constructor arguments if you'd like.